# Python script, no output?

Tags: python, file-io, hash, output

I have written a simple python script to hash a file and output the result. However, when I run the script (python scriptname.py), I don't get any output (expected it to print the checksum). I don't get any errors from the console either.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import hashlib
import sys

def sha256_checksum(filename, block_size=65536):

    sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
    filename = '/Desktop/testfile.txt'

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for block in iter(lambda: f.read(block_size), b''):
            sha256.update(block)
    return sha256.hexdigest()

def main():
    for f in sys.argv[1:]:
        checksum = sha256_checksum(f)
        print(f + '\t' + checksum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What other output are you expecting? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I expect the checksum / hash of the file to be printed by the line: print(f + '\t' + checksum)

Comment: Whoops, sorry, , read "expected it to print the checksum" as "except it to print the checksum". What is the value of `sys.argv[1:]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> def main():
>       for f in sys.argv[1:]:

The script expected arguments. If you run it without any arguments you don't see any ouput. 
The main body suppose that you provide list of files for hashing but in hashing function you hardcoded

> filename = '/Desktop/testfile.txt'

So, if you want to pass files for hashing as script arguments **remove the line**

> filename = '/Desktop/testfile.txt'

and run

```
python scriptname.py '/Desktop/testfile.txt'
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Also was not referencing the full path to the file.